# EntityFrameworkCore not batching Inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.2

When following one of the PluralSight courses on EntityFrameworkCore, I'm seeing different results from the video.  Namely, when calling `DbSet<...>.AddRange(item 1, item2)`, then `DbSet<...>.SaveChanges`, I'm seeing two simple INSERT statements instead of one complicated INSERT statement.

To recreate this in Visual Studio 2017:

1. Create a new .NET Framework Console App using C# 4.7.2.  Name it *SomeUI*.
2. Run the following commands in the Package Manager Console

   - `Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console SomeUI -Version 2.2.0`
   - `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer SomeUI -Version 2.2.6`
   - `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools SomeUI -Version 2.2.6`
3. Paste the code below as Program.cs.
4. Run the following commands in the Package Manager Console

   - `Add-Migration initial`
   - `Update-Database`

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SomeUI
{
    public class Samurai
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class SamuraiContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Samurai> Samurais { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseLoggerFactory(new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddLogging(builder => builder
                        .AddConsole()
                        .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information))
                    .BuildServiceProvider()
                    .GetService<ILoggerFactory>())
                .UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = SamuraiAppData; Trusted_Connection = True; ");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new SamuraiContext())
            {
                context.Samurais.AddRange(new Samurai { Name = "Jack" }, new Samurai { Name = "Jill" });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'SamuraiContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [Samurais] ([Name])
      VALUES (@p0);
      SELECT [Id]
      FROM [Samurais]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [Samurais] ([Name])
      VALUES (@p0);
      SELECT [Id]
      FROM [Samurais]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

What I should be seeing:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000)], @p1='?' (Size=4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);
      MERGE [Samurais] USING (
      VALUES (@p0, 0),
      (@p1, 1)) AS i ([Name], _Position) ON 1=0
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT ([Name])
      VALUES (i.[Name])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
      INTO @inserted0;

      SELECT [t].[Id] FROM [Samurais] t
      INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[Id] = [i].[Id])
      ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me get some insight here.

Comment: Where did you get that information? Last I checked EntityFramework does not support bulk insert.  Do they explictily show you what should be done in the SQL statement in the video? or are you basing this off of an assumption because of how the code looks?

Comment: I got that info from a PluralSight course titled _EntityFramework Core 2: Getting Started_.  She does mention that batch inserting is a relatively new feature and wasn't supported in EF Core 6.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't viewed the video but maybe the instructor was misinformed according to Entityframework you need to explictly call bulk insert to use bulk insert.

Comment: Try adding more Samurai, there may be a threshold for command batching.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft are you sure SQL bulk insert is support by EFCore all documentation I've seen states otherwise?  `AddRange` and `UpdateRange` are just convenience methods for adding to the context and does not dictate the strategy for saving

Comment: It's not bulk inserts, it's just batching.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, and this is my favorite answer, like, ever.

You simply don't have enough samurai.  Try seven:

```
  context.Samurais.AddRange(
         new Samurai { Name = "Kambei Shimada" }, 
         new Samurai { Name = "Gorōbei Katayama" },
         new Samurai { Name = "Shichirōji" },
         new Samurai { Name = "Kyūzō" },
         new Samurai { Name = "Heihachi Hayashida" },
         new Samurai { Name = "Katsushirō Okamoto" },
         new Samurai { Name = "Kikuchiyo" }
         );
```

And you'll see command batching kick in:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (210ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (Size = 4000), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);
      MERGE [Samurais] USING (
      VALUES (@p0, 0),
      (@p1, 1),
      (@p2, 2),
      (@p3, 3),
      (@p4, 4),
      (@p5, 5),
      (@p6, 6)) AS i ([Name], _Position) ON 1=0
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT ([Name])
      VALUES (i.[Name])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
      INTO @inserted0;

      SELECT [t].[Id] FROM [Samurais] t
      INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[Id] = [i].[Id])
      ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

You can configure the minimum or maximum batch size on the [SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsbuilder?view=efcore-2.1) in your DbContext's OnConfiguring method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification +1, Can you provide a link to some documentation on batching?

Comment: Added a link, but there's not a whole lot of documentation about relational batching, other than it exists, and _some_ relational providers support it.  But it's not always simple to implement.  Note the somewhat complex formulation required in SQL Server to insert multiple rows and fetch the generated IDs for the rows, and be able to match the un-keyed rows with the generated IDs.

Comment: Thanks, I see properties related to the batch size in there, this will help me alot in the future

Comment: @David Browne, thanks for the help.  I'm sure this changes frequently, but in my tests, batching began at 4 items.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, is it possible to do batch inserts for navigation properties? e.g. if there was a List<Samurai> for each Town? pseudo: `context.Towns.Samurais.AddRange(...);`

Comment: It shouldn't matter how the entities got into the Change Tracker.  SaveChanges() will see multiple Samarai in the Added state and create the inserts.  So it should batch the same.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thanks. I think what I'm running into is there isn't a valid way I can find to access `Towns.Samurais` without first pulling them all down from the database.

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new question with your model and an explanation of what you're trying to achieve.